# Trying to change a state in React Hooks with Interval

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem trying to change a state in react using `setInterval`.
Why does the function "alert" always show a "null" message?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const Playlist = (props) => {

  const [test, setTest] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(load, 3000)
  }, []);

  const load = async () => {
    alert(test)
    setTest("TEST");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {test}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Playlist
```

Answer (score 2):

**Issue :**

is callback passed into `setInterval`'s closure and it accesses the `test` variable in the first render.

**Solution :**

You can `clearInterval` and `setInterval` as soon as there is any changes in your state

```js
const { useState , useEffect , useCallback } = React;

const App = () => {

  const [test, setTest] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const intrvl = setInterval(load, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(intrvl);
  }, [test]);

  
  const load = () => {
    alert(test)
    setTest("TEST");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {test}
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `useEffect` captures the `test` from the first render which is equal to empty string. We never re-apply the effect so the closure in setInterval always references the test from the first render.

NOTE: `setInterval` does not describe a process in time — once you set the interval, you can’t change anything about it except clearing it.

When we pass an empty `[]` array of dependencies to useEffect, it only runs the useEffect on mount and cleanup on unmount of the component.

One way is to add `test` to the array of dependencies so anytime there is an update on test, the useEffect will be called.

```
 useEffect(() => {
   const intervalId = setInterval(load, 3000);
   return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
 }, [test]);
```

But since we are using the `test` inside useEffect, we can just remove the empty `[]` array of dependencies so the useEffect will be called every time we are setting the state (component is re-rendered) and the new setInterval will be created with accessing to the latest test state like below

```
useEffect(() => {
   const intervalId = setInterval(load, 3000);
   return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

Another possible way is to update the state inside the interval's closure like

```
useEffect(() => {
  const id = setInterval(() => {
    setTest("TEST");
  }, 3000);
  return () => clearInterval(id);
});
```

---

```
const App = () => {
  const [test, setTest] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(load, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  });

  const load = () => {
    alert(test)
    setTest("TEST");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {test}
    </div>
  )
}
```

[Example of interval with setting count so you can see the state change](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-mountain-xnm8v?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you, it's really complicated control the state with loops :P